# c# webbrowser coding to navigate local to html

Tags: c#, html, web, visual-studio-2013

I'm trying to put a local html location address to the web browser in my C# application but always failed. I'm using debug mode now so the html files had already copied into my Debug folder because i put copy always in the copy to output option.
Below is my code:

```
        string appPath = Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().CodeBase);
        string filePath = Path.Combine(appPath, "index.html");
        webBrowser1.Navigate(new System.Uri(@"file://"+ filePath));
```

There always this error coming out using that way:

```
An unhandled exception of type 'System.UriFormatException' occurred in System.dll
```

Any idea what went wrong?

Comment: What is the error you are getting?  Have you tried just hard coding the path to see if that works?  Have you checked in with the debugger what the actual value of `filePath` is and ensured that the file really is present at that location?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its a bit unclear but try this out. Hope this may help.

```
webBrowser1.Navigate(new Uri(@"your File Name"))
```

Or

```
webBrowser1.Navigate(new Uri(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory == "\\File Name")
```

Edit:
May be this causing error,

```
webBrowser1.Navigate(new System.Uri("@" filePath + "file://"));
```

Comment: If your file is in your directory just use the name no need to specified Directory Path

Comment: It will work if I directly put the file location inside. My file location is "C:\Work\Project 2015\Printing-io\Printing-io\Printing-io\bin\Debug\html". But I don't think this is the correct way. Because I'm doing debug now. I need the system to detect where it put.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to change your code slightly - here is the correct syntax:

```
string appPath = Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().CodeBase);
string filePath = Path.Combine(appPath, "index.html");
webBrowser1.Navigate(new System.Uri(filePath));
```

The issue is that [CodeBase](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assemblyname.codebase%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) returns the path in `URI` format already so you do not need to add the additional the "file://" to the path.